# Old OS showing up in Bootmgr.

Tags: windows-10, boot

I am not sure if this has been asked recently, but I cannot find the solution and I'm out of ideas.  Ordinarily if you wanted to remove an old OS from the boot menu you'd use BCEdit, or the Boot onfigurator in Msconfig, but neither shows the nonexistent OS' that appear on the Boot screen.

They aren't installed, and have been deleted.  The funny thing is that my actual OS doesn't even show up in the list, and I have to hit 'esc' to actually get into it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest you learn a little about BCD structure, its objects and elements and then use a tool like [Visual BCD Editor](https://www.boyans.net) which allows complete editing of every object and element in BCD.

Hitting ESC means you load another BCD if there are links to it in the default system BCD, else you reload the system BCD. See note on end of page in [Visual BCD Document](https://www.boyans.net/VisualBCD_doc.htm)

Default place for system BCD is "[active partition]\boot\BCD" on MBR disks or "[EFI System partition]\EFI\Microsoft\boot\BCD" on GPT disks.